# How do I calculate total minutes between start and end times?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I calculate total minutes between start and end times? The Start/End times columns are nvarchar and I am declaring them as datetime.  I'm not sure if that is my first step or not, I am new to SQL and to declaring.

The final goal is to take `Total Minutes`, subtract `Lunch` and `Recess` (both are minutes) and then multiply by 5 to get total instructional minutes for the week per school.

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime,  @Endtime datetime

SELECT --[School]
      [GradeLevel]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,(@Endtime - @StartTime) AS 'TotalMinutes'
      ,[Lunch]
      ,[Resess]
      ,[Passing]
  FROM [dbo].[StartEndTimes]


Current Output:
GradeLevel  StartTime   EndTime   TotalMinutes    Lunch   Resess    Passing
 2-5         7:50        14:20      NULL            20      10       NULL
 K-5         7:45        14:20      NULL            20      10       NULL
 K-5         7:50        14:20      NULL            20      10       NULL
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
select (datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) -lunch -recess) * 5 AS TotalInstruct
from YourTable
```

If you want to sum it up for all rows then try:

```
select sum((datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) -lunch -recess) * 5) AS TotalInstruct
from YourTable
```

If you want to get the number of hours per school you would have to include the `school`field in the query and use it in the `group by`clause, and then the query becomes this:

```
select school, sum((datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) -lunch -recess) * 5) AS TotalInstruct
from YourTable
group by school
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6118b/2) for the above queries.

Comment: Thank you JPW.  Yes this is the end result I am after.  I saw you edited my post.  Did I post something incorrectly?

Comment: @user3729714 No, my edits were just to improve formatting and adding a tag for [sql-server] to make the question easier to read and find. Oh, you shouldn't include tags in the title though. If you click on the edited link you can see exactly what I did.

Comment: @user3729714 I added grouping per school and a sample SQL Fiddle that you can look at.

Comment: Thank you JPW.  I forgot to mention, I need to subtract Passing as well.  The issue is, for many of my schools, passing is NULL.  When I add '- passing' to the end of the code you posted, it returns all NULL.  How do I account for NULL's in the Passing column?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3729714 You can use the [coalesce function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace NULL values with 0: `coalesce(passing,0)`. Another option would be `isnull(passing, 0)`

Comment: That works!  Thank you!  I appreciate your help in my SQL journey.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is to find the difference between two dates then you can use DATEDIFF function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Example:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2
SET @startdate = '2007-05-05 12:10:09.3312722';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2007-05-04 12:10:09.3312722'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @enddate, @startdate);
```

If however your values are in string format you need to convert them prior to passing them to the DATEDIFF function.
Example:

```
DECLARE @starttexttime nvarchar(100)
SET @starttexttime = '7:50'
DECLARE @starttime datetime2
SET @starttime = CONVERT(datetime2, @starttexttime, 0)

DECLARE @endtexttime nvarchar(100)
SET @endtexttime = '17:50'
DECLARE @endtime datetime2
SET @endtime = CONVERT(datetime2, @endtexttime, 0)

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @starttime, @endtime);
```

Comment: Thank you Lee.  I appreciate the help.  I will study your answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it should be :  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, startdate, enddate,);